# Can slower switching edges worsen the EMI behavior?

Tags: clock, switching, emc, high-frequency, emi-filtering

A common method (as stated in many electronic design articles/books) to reduce EMI (radiated emissions) of any fast switching circuit is to slow down it's switching edges (reduce t<sub>r</sub>/t<sub>f</sub>). This basically helps in reducing high frequency harmonic components in the switching signal.

My simplified understanding is:

Higher frequency components -> shorter wavelengths -> even shorter traces can already act as unintended radiators (antennas.)

Is it also possible that slower edges could make the situation worse from an EMI point of view?

To give a more practical example of my question:

On a PCB, a 20 MHz crystal oscillator with t<sub>r</sub>/t<sub>f</sub> of 2 ns is replaced by the same type of crystal oscillator with a t<sub>r</sub>/t<sub>f</sub> of 10 ns.

Is it possible or likely that radiated emissions get higher at some frequencies?

I'm pretty sure there is no clear answer to this and it may depend on many things, but I would like to know what aspects to consider.

Comment: "Is it possible or likely that radiated emissions get higher at some frequencies?" Well obviously the fundamental frequency + harmonics will be different and higher at the new frequency, if you change the frequency. I don't think I understand the question...

Comment: What do you mean by a "crystal oscillator"? Please show that part of the circuit. Normally the tracks from (say) an MCU to a crystal are very short and not very fast in rise times so, it seems unlikely that you mean a crystal oscillator. But, what do you mean?

Comment: A crystal oscillator is an oscillator in a can, that is crystal-controlled. It's not a crystal resonator connected to an MCU, it's a standalone part with logic level (sometimes sine) output. Not sure what confusion you guys are having...

Comment: Exactly, as Tim said correctly I meant a "crystal oscillator" (like this one: https://t.ly/CQzci).  A "crystal oscillator" is an active device (consisting of a "crystal resonator" and integrated circuitry for the oscillation) that usually has 4 or more pins, whereas a "crystal resonator" is a passive device with only 2 pins. I think these two terms are often confused. However, both can be used as a clock source for an MCU, in the case of a "crystal resonator" the oscillating circuit of the MCU is used.
Comparison: https://t.ly/iP0f

Answer (score 3):

At least one leg of a crystal is usually rather sinusoidal - 'scope one and see.  Their traces are usually short and right next to chip so these generally don't add much to radiated EMI.  Stick a ground plane under/over the area and it's essentially quiet.

The usual culprits for radiating EMI include:

- Any high-power circuitry which switches quickly (including SMPS, display backlight driver, DC-AC inverter, relay/contactor/solenoid drivers, etc.)
- Circuitry handling frequent load-dumps to distant devices (TVS across a relay, separated by long distance of wire = large coil inductance and relatively high parasitic wiring capacitance = oscillations.)
- Fast-transitioning signals on long (un-shielded) wires, like DVI, MIPI, LVDS, RS-485, etc.  These are shielded/differential-signaled-and-twisted to reduce both their emission and reception.  Try to run those over an unshielded flat-flex and problems can ensue.
- Fast transitions on long, non-transmission-line traces.
- Improper use of star-grounding (large ground transients) / ground loops.

> Can slower switching edges worsen EMI behavior?

In the frequency domain, every signal is comprised of a fundamental sine-wave and the sum of its harmonics.  Those harmonics can extend into the GHz range and are rather unavoidable for everything except a pure sine.  Like "ideal" components, a "pure" sine-wave is theoretical.

Imagine there were two unintentional radiators, one fast and one slow, but both nearly violating EMI limits.  Slow the fast one, and it *is possible* that the new sum of all frequencies + harmonics could violate the EMI limit at some frequency.

Emissions testing is often a multiple-revision process.  One or more unintentional radiators are found, then adjusted, then re-analyzed, adjusted again, etc.  For hobbyist/private use, your boards don't have to meet any EMI regulation (but you have to live with any interference it receives/creates.)  Products for sale however must meet EMI regulations, so must be tested.

If one wanted to get started in analyzing their own boards and assemblies (as a pre-cursor to emissions testing), they would need some [e/h-field probes](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=e-field+h-field+probe&t=opera&ia=web) and a signal analyzer capable of showing the frequencies of interest.  This is explained well by [w2aew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctynv2klT6Q).

Comment: I believe this assumes a crystal oscillator modules with a square wave output. Sure the crystal pins themselves would look sinusoidal.

Comment: An oscillator *module* will yes, generate harmonics into the hundreds of megahertz range; the faster the edge, the higher the harmonics will go.  Also if a clock module is 20MHz but is PLL'd to 96MHz (assume a microcontroller with internal PLL.)  If this has an instruction rate of 1/4, then every instruction can toggle some pin at 96/4=24MHz - so you might (spectrally) see a bump at 20MHz+harmonics from the oscillator module, a bump at 24MHz+/-harmonics from any *active traces* at that moment, and a small bump at 96MHz+harmonics at the chip itself.

Comment: If chip has a PLL and there is a clock at 96 MHz, it will internally gulp current at 96 MHz for each phase for executing an instruction, not just at 24 MHz for each instruction.

Comment: Right, but that will be localized to the chip, not coupled to every device connected to it.

Comment: Assuming bypass capacitance is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

If the EMI system is such that the emissions are directly proportional to the level from the oscillator, then a strict reduction in levels at the oscillator will reduce the emissions proportionally.

Seems simple enough, but that's a big chain of assumptions.  The same clock might be used by many devices on the board, thus its peaks show up, coherently, throughout the board.  To satisfy the above, you must prove that it's the clock trace itself, not a derived/related signal.

What if the new oscillator is not slower per se, but weaker (that is, higher output impedance)?  Now the system is different: different impedance means different coupling factors and frequency response.  *Most likely*, it will still be lower (indeed doubly so), because higher impedance from the same supply (assuming a CMOS type output here) simply means less available power, even if the EMI path were perfectly coupled to the oscillator in both cases (and it could only be perfectly coupled in one of those cases, all else held equal).

But I could also imagine a situation where a controlled-rise oscillator is employed, which has the slew rate or filtering internal, and still has a low-impedance output (perhaps it's implemented by a Miller capacitance at the output inverter, so has a low impedance \$Z_o \approx \frac{1}{g_m}\$ during the transition) which therefore couples more strongly into the system.  It's still not clear if that could ever give higher levels, but it shows things are more complicated than they might seem.

A related, and probably more practical example, might be a sine-output type oscillator.  Mind, these aren't compatible with logic-level inputs, but the output may be active, such as an op-amp buffer.  This will have some manner of output impedance, though whether it's high or low at the driving frequency (or susceptible to oscillation at other frequencies, due to C-loading for example) is obviously hard to say; beyond that they're probably not going to be far from the 50 ohm ballpark, just for practical reasons.  (But current-sourcing models might exist, too, in which case you must provide termination resistors.)

There are other sneak paths, like the supply pins; especially in the latter (Miller slew rate limited) example, the higher capacitance around the output driver (and this is all onboard the chip, remember) implies it may draw higher / spikier currents from the supply.  Which can therefore result in more supply ripple, common-mode noise (the spiky return currents through the chip's ground pins/wirebonds results in some lifting of its output that isn't related to the bulk of the output voltage swing, but added to it), and radiation.  Or more feed-forward signal (edges from internal gates, coupling through the Miller capacitor) reaches the output.  But again, these are more rather, examples of how devices can differ -- often in subtle and undocumented ways -- than apples-to-apples comparisons.

So, suffice it to say, everything depends; the important part is to be able to find what parameters it depends upon, to track it down and find the culprits.

And that's not to mention side-effects of slow rise, as other have mentioned; honor the maximum risetime spec of all logic inputs.  Schmitt trigger inputs may be preferred, also increasing noise immunity.

Or that filtering increases propagation delay, which may violate timing loops.  Consider an SPI device for example, say you need to communicate with one on a couple-meters-long cable.  So you apply filtering (say a 330R ferrite bead and 220pF cap) and run the logic signals that way.  The SPI host clocks in received data at its transmit clock rate, not the clock seem by the peripheral.  In this example, you might be limited to a bit rate under 5MHz, before returned data gets corrupted.  (When higher rates are required, it's viable to return the peripheral's clock (buffered and re-transmitted) and data together to an independent SPI channel on the host; this costs an extra wire or two in the cable.)  (Also, when such bandwidths are required, shielded cable is pretty much mandatory, or RS-422 transmitters and receivers can be employed; or better still, both!)

Answer (score 0):

So if we remove energy from higher harmonics such that they roll off at a lower frequency with the same 20MHz period? No, that will not increase radiated emissions as there is less energy or the same at any given frequency.
What possible problems could this cause? Depends on the timing diagrams

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that radiated emissions will be increased in your example.

But consider something more extreme. For example, if we slow the clock down to 10 Hz, with rise and fall times of 10 ms.

With such a slow rise/fall time, it's possible that some logic driven by the clock will chatter due to the long time spent in the transition between valid high and low logic levels. This chatter could produce higher emissions than you would have seen if the clock were driven fast enough for the circuit to behave as intended.